# Unable to display values inside the Body of the email in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, I wanted to get the values of `Sample.js` and want to send the values through email. But i couldn't able to store the values in `body` of the email. I've tried in storing the values in `Info` within render but couldn't able to store in `Body`. Can anyone help me in getting the value in Body of the content?

Sample.js code:

```
 <div>
        <SendD data={this.state} />
        <b>Firstname: {this.state.firstName} </b>
        <br />
        <b>Lastname: {this.state.lastName} </b>
        <br />
        <b>Age: {this.state.age} </b>
      </div>
```

Send Data Code:

```
const Info = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <b>FirstName: {this.props.data.firstName}</b>
          <b>Last Name: {this.props.data.LastName}</b>
          <b>age: {this.props.data.age}</b>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Body.js code:

```
<Body
                label="Body"
                name="body"
                value={this.state.body}
                onChange={this.changeBodyHandler}
              />
```

[Whole Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dream-hmhpf)

how to put these values inside the body of the email?

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Your "Whole Code" link has a syntax error stopping it from loading.

Comment: @DBS - because it is local link, Could you please click on close icon so that we could get the output